# Spark executors fails on Kubernetes - resourceProfileId is missing

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to upgrade from Spark 3.0.1 to 3.1.1.

I am running PySpark 3.1.1 in client mode on Jupyter notebook.

The following ran on 3.0.1 but fails after upgrading spark:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession



def get_spark_session(app_name: str, conf: SparkConf):
    conf.setMaster("k8s://https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local")
    conf \
      .set("spark.kubernetes.namespace", "spark-ml") \
      .set("spark.kubernetes.container.image", "itayb/spark:3.1.1-hadoop-3.2.0-python-3.8.6-aws") \
      .set("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName", "spark-executor") \
      .set("spark.executor.instances", "2") \
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g") \
      .set("spark.executor.cores", "2") \
      .set("spark.driver.memory", "1G") \
      .set("spark.driver.port", "2222") \
      .set("spark.driver.blockManager.port", "7777") \
      .set("spark.driver.host", "jupyter.recs.svc.cluster.local") \
      .set("spark.driver.bindAddress", "0.0.0.0") \
      .set("spark.ui.port", "4040") \
      .set("spark.network.timeout", "240") \
      .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "localstack.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:4566") \
      .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false") \
      .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true") \
      .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") \
      .set("spark.hadoop.com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true") \
      .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider")
    return SparkSession.builder.appName(app_name).config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()


spark = get_spark_session("aws_localstack", SparkConf())
try:
    df = spark.read.csv('s3a://my-bucket/stocks.csv',header=True)
    df.printSchema()
    print(df.count())
except Exception as exp:
    print(exp)
    
spark.stop()
```

The executors logs:

```
+ SPARK_CLASSPATH=':/opt/spark/jars/*'                                                                                                                                    │
+ env                                                                                                                                                                     │
+ grep SPARK_JAVA_OPT_                                                                                                                                                    │
+ sort -t_ -k4 -n                                                                                                                                                         │
+ sed 's/[^=]*=\(.*\)/\1/g'                                                                                                                                               │
+ readarray -t SPARK_EXECUTOR_JAVA_OPTS                                                                                                                                   │
+ '[' -n '' ']'                                                                                                                                                           │
+ '[' -z ']'                                                                                                                                                              │
+ '[' -z ']'                                                                                                                                                              │
+ '[' -n '' ']'                                                                                                                                                           │
+ '[' -z ']'                                                                                                                                                              │
+ '[' -z x ']'                                                                                                                                                            │
+ SPARK_CLASSPATH='/opt/spark/conf::/opt/spark/jars/*'                                                                                                                    │
+ case "$1" in                                                                                                                                                            │
+ shift 1                                                                                                                                                                 │
+ CMD=(${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java "${SPARK_EXECUTOR_JAVA_OPTS[@]}" -Xms$SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY -Xmx$SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY -cp "$SPARK_CLASSPATH:$SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH" org.apac │
+ exec /usr/bin/tini -s -- /usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java -Dspark.network.timeout=240 -Dspark.driver.port=2222 -Dspark.ui.port=4040 -Dspark.driver.blockManager.port=7777 │
Unrecognized options: --resourceProfileId                                                                                                                                 │
Usage: org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend [options]                                                                                                   │
 Options are:                                                                                                                                                             │
   --driver-url <driverUrl>                                                                                                                                               │
   --executor-id <executorId>                                                                                                                                             │
   --bind-address <bindAddress>                                                                                                                                           │
   --hostname <hostname>                                                                                                                                                  │
   --cores <cores>                                                                                                                                                        │
   --resourcesFile <fileWithJSONResourceInformation>                                                                                                                      │
   --app-id <appid>                                                                                                                                                       │
   --worker-url <workerUrl>                                                                                                                                               │
   --user-class-path <url>                                                                                                                                                │
   --resourceProfileId <id>                                                                                                                                               │
stream closed
```

seems like `--resourceProfileId` doesn't have value, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my bad :(

I used different Spark versions between the driver (3.1.1) and executors (3.0.1).

The mistake happened because I tried to build the executor image from the [official repo](https://github.com/apache/spark) by simply checking out to the `v3.1.1` tag and use the

```
./bin/docker-image-tool.sh
```

I guess that I had to compile or something before because the version was older.
I verified that by `exec` to the worker container and run:

```
spark-submit --version
```

The fast solution was to download the right compiled version (instead of using the source), extract and build:

```
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.1.1/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
tar xvzf spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
cd spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -u root -r itayb -t 3.1.1-hadoop-3.2.0 -p kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/python/Dockerfile build
```

Answer (score -1):

See the discussion at the spark pr page - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33288?focusedCommentId=17296060&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17296060